# Can I use webpack to convert multiple .epub files at once using config file and how?

Tags: webpack, epub, epub3

```
var fs= require('fs');
var epubZip= require('epub-zip');
var content = epubZip('./tests/epubs/epub1');
var content2= epubZip('./tests/epubs/epub2');
fs.writeFileSync("./tests/dist/epub1.epub",content);
fs.writeFileSync("./tests/dist/epub2.epub",content2);
```

For example this is the code used to generate 2 epub files, how can I get automatically multiple outputs just by writing only one fs.writeFileSync function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getDirectories(mypath) {
    return fs.readdirSync(mypath).filter(function(file) {
        if(fs.statSync(path.join(mypath, file)).isDirectory()) {
            //console.log('mypath is :',file);
            var newpath = mypath+'/'+file;
            //console.log('newpath is:'+newpath);
            var content =epubZip(newpath);
            var writepath=mywritepath+'/'+file+'.epub';
            //console.log('writepath is:'+writepath);
             fs.writeFileSync(writepath,content);
        }
```

This is how I fixed my issue, appended my directory name to the path